# UICollectionView, how to prevent one cell from being moved

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I recently study collection view. I need to let some cells fix in their own index path, which mean they should not be exchanged by others and not be dragged. I now can use *- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView canMoveItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath* to prevent them from dragging. I cannot prevent them from being exchanged by other cells.

Any one meet same issue?

Thanks

Comment: We will need more context in order to help you. Can you provide a schema or a XIB file illustrating the layout you want to achieve concerning the cells. Do they (the one that don't move) have specific position?

Comment: The question was perfectly clear...

Answer (score 10):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, targetIndexPathForMoveFromItemAt originalIndexPath: IndexPath, toProposedIndexPath proposedIndexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath {
    if proposedIndexPath.row == data.count {
        return IndexPath(row: proposedIndexPath.row - 1, section: proposedIndexPath.section)
    } else {
        return proposedIndexPath
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I found that when I used iOS 11+ drag and drop, `targetIndexPathForMoveFromItemAt` wouldn't get called. Implementing this method forbids the item from being dropped where I don't want it:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewDropProposal {
    // disallow dragging across sections
    guard let sourcePath = session.items.first?.localObject as? IndexPath,
        let destPath = destinationIndexPath,
        sourcePath.section == destPath.section
        else {
            return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .forbidden)
    }
    return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
}
```

Note that I stored the source index path in `localObject` when the drag started, because I couldn't find a way to get this information otherwise.

Comment: For some reason when you scroll and drag a long horizontal collectionView, the forbidden cells still move aside. The dropping still gets canceled (dropped cell fades instead of getting inserted, which is good). But it's not the best UX. Could it be a Apple bug?

Answer (score 3):

In this example you can't move the first and last component of your array in your CollectionView 
You can use porposedIndexPath, this is for UiCollectionView delegate

**Swift 3**

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, targetIndexPathForMoveFromItemAt originalIndexPath: IndexPath, toProposedIndexPath proposedIndexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath {
                if proposedIndexPath.row == 0 ||   proposedIndexPath.row == yourArray.count - 1{
                    return IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
                }
                return proposedIndexPath
            }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code only answers are not useful for learners.

Comment: I added this method to my delegate but it doesn't get called. In the same delegate I have other methods like canMoveItemAt which gets called ok. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, to use this method I had to override the delegate in my class `configure` method, by doing `self.delegate = self`. Now the problem I have is that for the movement I want to prevent (swapping of last two cells), it gets called with both original and proposed indexes set to the same row number.

Comment: you can try in func of delegate canMoveItemAt.. this
if indexPath.row == yourArray - 1 || indexPath.row == yourArray - 2 {return false} else{return true} and in your func of delegate targetIndexPathForMoveFromItemAt put same this if proposedIndexPath.row == yourArray.count - 1 || proposedIndexPath.row == yourArray.count - 2{ return IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0) } return proposedIndexPath

Answer (score 2):

Try using `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
targetIndexPathForMoveFromItemAt originalIndexPath: IndexPath, 
         toProposedIndexPath proposedIndexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath`

See Apple's docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618052-collectionview

> During the interactive moving of an item, the collection view calls
>   this method to see if you want to provide a different index path than
>   the proposed path. You might use this method to prevent the user from
>   dropping the item in an invalid location. For example, you might
>   prevent the user from dropping the item in a specific section.

So for example, if you wanted to prevent reordering a cell with the last cell you could do:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, targetIndexPathForMoveFromItemAt originalIndexPath: IndexPath, toProposedIndexPath proposedIndexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath {
    if proposedIndexPath.row == data.count {
        return IndexPath(row: proposedIndexPath.row - 1, section: proposedIndexPath.section)
    } else {
        return proposedIndexPath
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good, but the way you wrote it only protects against the index after the last allowable index. You should change the `row: ` argument to whatever spot you want to default to in case the proposedRow should be invalid (I.e. non-movable).